# how to setup minimum textlines before new page?

Tags: page-breaking, layout

I have a 130 pages thesis, that has many chapters starting in the lower 5/6 of the page and having only 3-5 lines of text before it wraps to a new page.

If I have to manual add `\newpage` below every chapter, I will not get done in time as it changes with every `\newpage` the whole document.(every build will change the wrapped chapters and chopped chapters...)

Is there a possibility to configure a minimum of Textlines to be set on a Page?

like: "if it does NOT have enough space, then wrap the whole chapter to the next page"?

Comment: you can use the needspace package.

Comment: We have no idea what class you are using but with the standard classes a `\chapter` command starts a new page. Please provide an MWE to show what you are doing.

Comment: it is impossible to guess the problem with your code if you show no example I don't think I have ever seen a class that didn't make `\chapter` start a new page so why do you need `\newpage`????

Comment: well my env is a article and it wraps sections automaticaly to a new page as standard. I used the term chapter as i thaught each sub element of a section is generaly called a chapter. Its those sub-elements of sections that i am asking about. Neverless i do not agree that a mwe is needed here becaus as i wrote my document is 130 pages long and its nonesence to make mwe of the critical sections. The question is clear enough.